# How is $P(X = x) = \sum_{t} 1_{\{X(t)=x\}}P(t)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In what follows, $X,Y$ are random variables on the space $\Omega$ and $g(X) : \omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function.

$\color{red} {(1)}$ How is $P(X = x) = \displaystyle\sum_{t} 1_{\{X(t)=x\}}P(t)$. How do we know that the events are independent so that they can just "add up" that way? (For independent events, $\displaystyle P\left(\bigcup_i E_i\right) = \sum_i P(X_i)$ which is not necessarily true for non-mutually-exclusive events).

Now how does $\color{red} {(2)}$ $yP(Y=g(x)) = \displaystyle\sum_{x : g(x) = y} P(X=x)?$ where we have defined $Y = g(X)$. Is it straight forward from the previous result?

I have a follow-up question $\color{red} {(3)}$ : Is it $Y(y) = g(X(y))$? I don't see anything else since they are functions.

Comment: I am assuming here that $\Omega$ is finite or countably infinite? In that case, indeed we would have
$$
\mathbb P(\omega\in\Omega: X(\omega) = x) = \sum_{\omega\in\Omega}\mathsf 1_{\{X(\omega)=x\}}\mathbb P(\{\omega\}).
$$

Comment: What exactly does $P(\omega)$ mean? Loosely speaking, is it something like $\frac{\text{count}(\omega)}{|\Omega|}$? (I understand that $\text{Pr}$ might not always be evaluated, for example, $P(X=0)$ provided that $X(n < 3)=1$ and $X(n \geq 3)=0$

Comment: It's $\mathbb P(\{\omega\})$, not $\mathbb P(\omega)$. If you have a discrete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal P(\Omega), \mathbb P)$ then $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure that assigns to each subset of $\Omega$ a value between zero and one. The formula $\mathbb P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|\Omega|}$ is only valid when $\mathbb P$ is the uniform probability measure over a finite set $\Omega$. What I wrote in my answer is more general and applies for arbitrary probability measures over finite or countably infinite $\Omega$.

Comment: Got you, thanks!